# which is the correct methode for declaring cursor?

Tags: mariadb

I am creating a cursor in mariadb but some error is occur,so tell me how
    can I fix this error

```
 create table o_rollcall(roll_no int (3),name varchar(30));
 insert into o_rollcall values (1,'safwan'),(2,'abc'),(3,'xyz');
 create table n_rollcall(roll_no int (3),name varchar(30));
 insert into n_rollcall values (1,'safwan');


MariaDB [c]> declare
-> cursor cur1 for select roll_no,name from o_rollcall;

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual   
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to   
use near 'declare
cursor cur1 for select roll_no,name from o_rollcall' at line 1
```